# How to fix AWS S3 error: socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pentaho, amazon-emr, rundeck

We have a long running Pentaho job in Rundeck that has recently started to experience failures.

The Rundeck step definition is:

```
  echo "Using AMI $(aws ec2 describe-images --owners 660354881677 --filters 'Name=name,Values="ds-pentaho-v1.15.0"' --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].ImageId' --output text)"
  /usr/local/bin/pentaho-cli run-ec2 --environment prd \
  --ami-id $(aws ec2 describe-images --owners 660354881677 --filters 'Name=name,Values="ds-pentaho-v1.15.0"' --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].ImageId' --output text) \
  --arg BOOL_ARG_1=true \
  --instance-type "m5.2xlarge" \
  --on-demand \
  --max-fleet-retries "2" \
  --emr-host "some_emr_host.net" \
  --dir "/some/job/path/" \
  --job "some_job_name"
```

Specifically, the job has gone from consistently completing to not completing and just hangs in a long-running status. Digging through the logs, we find this:

```
2022/12/02 06:21:31 - tfo: task_read_table_2 - linenr 13900000
2022/12/02 06:21:11 - tfo: task_read_table_1 - linenr 900000 <- Last Line output for table 1 here
2022/12/02 06:21:59 - tfo: task_read_table_2 - linenr 15150000
2022/12/02 06:22:00 - tfo: task_read_table_2 - linenr 15200000
2022/12/02 06:22:01 - tfo: task_read_table_2 - linenr 15250000
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your socket
connection to the server was not read from or written to within the
timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (Service: Amazon S3;
Status Code: 400; Error Code: RequestTimeout;
2022/12/02 06:22:02 - tfo: task_read_table_2 - linenr 15300000
2022/12/02 06:22:03 - tfo: task_read_table_2 - linenr 15350000
2022/12/02 06:24:52 - in: task_read_table_2 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2022/12/02 06:24:54 - tfo: task_read_table_3 - linenr 50000
...
2022/12/02 06:35:53 - tfo: task_read_table_3 - linenr 37500000
2022/12/02 06:35:54 Finished reading query, closing connection.
<The job hangs here!>
```

The AWS S3 exception above occurs anywhere between 10 minutes and 2 hours of the job running.

The job is on a parallel step that is pulling data from multiple PostgreSQL server tables and loading the data into S3 with a `text output task`. It seems like S3 is hanging up after the read on `task_read_table_1` - the data is not written to S3. The job continues to pull records from the other source tables until completion, but it never writes those table outputs to S3 either. From there, the job just hangs. The site engineers are not sure what is going on here. I think this may be an issue with how either AWS or Rundeck are setup. Note: we use `terraform` to manage timeouts and those are currently set to 24 hours, which is well within the timeout period.

The number of records between successful and unsuccessful runs appears to be the same. There does not appear to be much recent reliable search results on the internet - most results are 5-10 years old, which does not seem relevant.

I do not think this is a problem with the Pentaho job itself because it has completed without fail in the past and the overall records counts of what is being pulled/loaded is stable.

Does anyone know what is potentially causing this issue or how it can be diagnosed?

Note: This is my first engagement working with AWS, Rundeck, Terraform, and Pentaho. I am more of an ETL developer than a site engineer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you test running that script manually from the Rundeck server? It seems a connectivity problem.

Comment: Yes, I logged into it and ran the job manually over multiple days. All runs have eventually hung. I agree that it is a connectivity issue, but I am not sure how to diagnose and troubleshoot it.

Comment: @JWeezy I have the same issue that pops up randomly while uploading a large amount of files with differents sizes. How did you end up fixing it?

Comment: @Nico No, we did not. The solution was to abandon Glue and go with a custom PySpark pipeline.